# How do I create pulse of 200 ns and 10 V with a microcontroller?

Tags: arduino, avr, high-frequency

I 'd like to command the gate of a MOSFET with a microcontroller. The command will be be very short: a pulse with 200 ns of duration (period = 1 ms) and about 10 V of amplitude.
Can I do this with an Arduino? Or with another microcontroller?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is to use a MOSFET gate driver.  This is exactly what they are for.  Using "MOSFET gate driver" should allow you find lots of information about them, and to find specific parts on distributor web sites.

Comment: Pick a FET with a low gate threshold (logic level) and low gate capacitance and you can drive it directly.

Comment: @John: Yes, but note that such FETs are only available up to about 30 V and a few amps.  FETs that can withstand more voltage and conduct more current usually require 10-15 V gate drive.

Answer (score 1):

Olin Lathrop is correct, the best way is to use an off the shelf MOSFET gate driver.  There are a lot to choose from, so make sure that the device you use has logic level inputs, can operate from a 10V rail and has rise/fall times that will work for your MOSFET and timing requirements.
For example, the [Texas Instruments LM5114B](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5114.pdf) should work well if your MOSFET doesn't have more than 1000pF of gate capacitance.

Regarding the microcontroller... it depends. I don't think the Arduino can generate a 5MHz PWM frequency. Microchip makes a number of parts that can generate a PWM signal that is some fraction of the system clock, so you may have better luck with those parts. For example, the [dsPIC33E/dsPIC33F](http://www.microchip.com/design-centers/16-bit/products/dspic33f-e).

Microchip offers the [PIC24F04KL100](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC24F04KL100), which has 2 PWM channels with a resolution of 15ns for $0.84; or there is the [dsPIC33FJ06GS001](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/dsPIC33FJ06GS001) with 4 channels with a resolution of 1ns for $1.61.

Comment: Where did the stuff about 5 MHz PWM come from? It isn't in the question. The OP just needs a 1 kHz pulse train with 200-ns on time.

Comment: @DaveTweed The 5 MHz refers to the 200 ns minimum  resolution needed for the pulse width.